# MongoDB does not match diacritic insensitive

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have read and re-read the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-index-diacritic-insensitivity), looked on SO and Google for an answer, but I cannot find a reason for this.

I have a collection which I declare as such

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'

export default InventoryItems = new Meteor.Collection('inventory-items');


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/

  InventoryItems._ensureIndex({ sku: 1 }, {
    name: 'UniqueIndex',
    unique: true
  });

  InventoryItems._ensureIndex({ sku: 'text', name: 'text', description: 'text' }, {
    name: 'SearchIndex',
    weights: {
      sku: 10,
      name: 5,
      description: 1
    },
    default_language: 'french'
  });
}
```

Then, given these entries

```
InventoryItems.insert({ sku:'B-WA', name:'Barrière WA', description:'' });
InventoryItems.insert({ sku:'B-WT', name:'Barrière WT', description:'' });
InventoryItems.insert({ sku:'B-WL', name:'Barrière WL', description:'' });
```

and search

```
InventoryItems.find({ $text: { $search: 'barrier' } });
```

it returns the entire collection, but if I do

```
InventoryItems.find({ $text: { $search: 'barriere' } });
```

it returns *nothing*! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Why is the first one matching, but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is the stemming feature which reduces the words to their root base. In your case, the tokenizer just made your word "barrier".
Found this [blog](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/01/text-search-mongodb-stemming/) with a very nice article about this (and other tokenizer features) on text indexes.